# Extension of Taylor expansion of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Suppose I have a complex function $g(z)$ defined on a disk $|z|\leq R$. If $g(z)$ is analytic on a smaller disk, say $|z|\leq R/2$, and thus have Taylor expansion $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n z^n$ on $|z|\leq R/2$, can we say that $g(z)$ can also be expressed as this Taylor expansion on $|z|\leq R$? Why?

Comment: First, it is better to use open discs when talking about analyticity. Your claim is true only if $g(z)$ is analytic on $|z|<R$.

Comment: Can you also explain why is it true in that case?

Comment: It follows from Cauchy's formula. If $g$ is analytic on $|z|<R$, you can derive its power series about the origin using the Cauchy formula and show that it converges on $|z|<R$. This power series must be the same as the one you have on $|z|<R/2$. Conversely, if $g$ is represented by that series on $|z|<R$ then, since the power series is an analytic function, $g$ is analytic on $|z|<R$.